# How to create a matrix in matlab using variables?

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have four variables which I created using NetCDF data namely
height, lat, long and date.
Now I want to create a single matrix with these variables as a column then I supposed to neglect values containing "NAN" data.

I have done this separately, but I want in a single matrix.
I have to run this process on multiple files.

```
for i = 1:length(theFiles)% Loop for each nc-file
    %Select Single cycle
    FileName = theFiles(i).name; 

    FullPathName=fullfile(folder_name, FileName); %reading file one by one
    disp(['File selected:', FullPathName])


    [Height,time,Lat,Long]=read_netcdf(FullPathName);  % Read the selected nc file 
     lattiude=Lat;
     longitude=Long;

     B = [Height,time,Lat,Long];   
    end
```

One more thing, total no. of data is 579X1 all variable but as I remove Nan value from Height, its dimension reduces to 45X1 
Now what I am trying to do is to reduce all the variables dimensions w.r.t Height.

I have got my matrix, now wanted to remove all rows containing Nan Value

> NaN   736536.710457717    28.3771283105297    69.6958150783291
>   NaN   736536.710457858    28.3778490697636    69.6956231314990
>   75    736536.710458284    28.3800119048871    69.6950471308031
>   75    736536.710458426    28.3807327583405    69.6948551510433
>   NaN   736536.710458000    28.3785699096006    69.6954311612445
>   NaN   736536.710458142    28.3792909110158    69.6952391459993

Comment: I am processing the NetCDF file of Sentinel 3. It contains water level information, what I required is a single matrix containing other than NAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can increase the size of arrays like this:

```
for i = 1:n
   B = [B; newValue];
end
```